# How to unistall Tauon Music Player?

Tags: uninstall, music

I installed the Tauon Music Player flatpack because it has a lot of positive reviews, but it's not what I'm looking for in a player. How can I uninstall it?

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and installed the player like this:

```
flatpak install flathub com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb
```

Comment: Hello. Several things. What version of Ubuntu? What was the exact command you used to install it? I tried it but honestly it isn't all that, what does this mean?

Comment: The latest version of Ubuntu. By that I mean I heard loads of positive stuff about this music player but I found it pretty poor to be honest.

Comment: There is not such version of Ubuntu as latest. Ubuntu uses version numbers. There are at least 2 that can be called latest.

Comment: 20.04.4 is the version I am using

Comment: OK so if you can give me the command you used to install it I might be able to tell you how to remove it.

Comment: flatpak install flathub com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove a program you have installed with flatpak you use the flatpak command.

How do I remove apps from my flatpak?

flatpak is the primary Flatpak command, to which specific commands are appended. For example, the command to install something is

```
flatpak install app name
```

and the command to uninstall is

```
flatpak uninstall app name
```

so the following should remove the app you want to get rid of.

```
flatpak uninstall tauonmb
```

Comment: @CJUK it looks like you up voted but did not accept the answer,

Comment: Don't know how to do that

Comment: @CJUK This may help you: https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer